# Drawing Ellipse from a bounding box?

Tags: c++, algorithms, graphics

Does anyone know a good algorithm for drawing an ellipse from a bounding box?

```
draw_ellipse(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, color c);
```

I don't need something optimized to incomprehendable , unreadable efficiency. Just something good enough to use for a simple drawing api. You can provide the algorithm in your answer in all programming languages or even pseudocode, but I would prefer it if you use C++ or a C++-like syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very basic and completely untested pseudo-code for drawing an ellipse using a parametric polar equation is below:

```
Function draw_ellipse(int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2)
     RX = (X2 - X1) / 2
     RY = (Y2 - Y1) / 2
     CX = (X2 + X1) / 2
     CY = (Y2 + Y1) / 2

     for Angle = 0 to 360
          X = CX + cos(Angle) * RX
          Y = CY + sin(Angle) * RY

          if (Angle > 0) DrawLine(LastX, LastY, X, Y)

          LastX = X
          LastY = Y
     Next Angle
End Function
```

Notes/Comments:

- Assumes an unrotated ellipse.
- Change to radians (0 to 2 pi) if your language cos/sin takes angles in radians (like C/C+ does).
- You can use symmetry to reduce the loop size to 0 - 90 degrees.
- Change the drawing precision as needed by changing the loop step amount (is 1 degree as shown).

Answer (score 2):

Normally I have defined an ellipse with the center point, semi-major, semi-minor, and the angle of rotation.

What you have described is a ellipse that the center point needs to be determined, and is not rotated The most widely used algorithm in graphics for a circle is by Bresenham, [Kennedy](http://homepage.smc.edu/kennedy_john/belipse.pdf) adapted it for an ellipse.